# Add Total Row To PIVOT Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I want to add a TOTAL monthly row to my query, below is my DDL, how can I have an additional row, under the last `employeename` that is labeled `TOTAL` and it shows the `SUM()` of the sales for **ALL** employees for that month?

```
Create Table #empSales
(
    employeename varchar(100)
    ,saleamt decimal(10,2)
    ,saleMonth varchar(100)
)

Insert Into #empSales VALUES
('James', '1.00', 'January')
,('Richard', '3.28', 'January')
,('Barb', '4.13', 'January')


Select 
employeeName
,SUM(January) As JanAMt
,SUM(February) As FebAMt
,SUM(March) As MarAMt
,SUM(April) As AprAMt
,SUM(May) As MayAMt
,SUM(June) As JunAMt
,SUM(July) As JulAMt
,SUM(August) As AugAMt
,SUM(September) As SepAMt
,SUM(October) As OctAMt
,SUM(November) As NovAMt
,SUM(December) As DecAMt
FROM #empSales
PIVOT ( 
    SUM(saleAmt) For saleMonth IN (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)
) As pvt
GROUP BY employeeName
Order By employeeName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional `WITH ROLLUP` clause can be added to your `GROUP BY` in order to get the grand total row.

```
GROUP BY employeeName WITH ROLLUP
```

To get "TOTAL" as the label, you can use [the `GROUPING` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
Select 
CASE WHEN GROUPING(employeename) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE employeeName END
```

The final query looks like this:

```
Select 
CASE WHEN GROUPING(employeename) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE employeeName END
,SUM(January) As JanAMt
,SUM(February) As FebAMt
,SUM(March) As MarAMt
,SUM(April) As AprAMt
,SUM(May) As MayAMt
,SUM(June) As JunAMt
,SUM(July) As JulAMt
,SUM(August) As AugAMt
,SUM(September) As SepAMt
,SUM(October) As OctAMt
,SUM(November) As NovAMt
,SUM(December) As DecAMt
FROM #empSales
PIVOT ( 
    SUM(saleAmt) For saleMonth IN (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)
) As pvt
GROUP BY employeeName WITH ROLLUP
Order By GROUPING(employeename), employeeName
```

[image: screenshot of results with the TOTAL row]

Notice that I tweaked the `ORDER BY` so that the total row comes last in the resultset.